# Function of type void can't be assigned to type Observable<any>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I want to search a list of users fetched from an API. I first initialize the list and then I want to be able to filter the usernames of the list. I have built the logic with async observables. But within my second func. `searchList()` I get an error on `this.userList` => `Function of type void can't be assigned to type Observable<any>` and in my console:

> _co.searchChanged is not a function

I really can't tell why that gives an error.

MY CODE:

service.ts

```
// get the user list from the api
getList(offset = 0): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users?offset=${offset}&limit=10`)
  }
```

page.ts

```
 public searchTerm: string = "";
 userList: Observable<any>;

constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

 ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllUsers();   // intialize the userList which should be searched
 }

  // function to map the users
  getAllUsers() { 
    this.userList = this.userService.getList(this.offset) 
    .pipe(map(response => response.results));
  }

  // filter the users for username
  filterUsers(searchTerm) {
    this.userList.subscribe(res => {
      const result = res.filter(user => {
        return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      return result;
    });
  }

  searchList() {
    this.userList = this.filterUsers(this.searchTerm);  // here I get the error
  }
```

page.html

```
<ion-searchbar mode="ios" class="items-searchbar" animated mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="searchList()" placeholder="Filter by name..."></ion-searchbar>
...
<ion-list>
    <ion-item  lines="none" *ngFor="let user of (userList | async); let i = index">
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: It is like the error says: `userList` expects `Observable<any>`, but `this.filterUsers(this.searchTerm)` has the type `void` as nothing is returned in the function body.

Comment: I don't really get what I have to return since I'm already returning the result in `filterUsers()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Function of type void can't be assigned to type Observable.

The error message says that `userList` is expecting an observable to be assigned but `filterUsers()` isn't returning anything, so `void` is returned and assigned.

Modify `fitlerUsers()` function to return an observable. I'm using [map()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator to transform the results.

```
filterUsers(searchTerm) {
  return this.userList.pipe(
    map(res => {
      const result = res.filter(user => {
        return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      return result;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: thx that fixed my error. But, bizarrely the search function is not working:/

Comment: @ColinRagnarök - I don't see why it wouldn't work. If you can reproduce this code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) or similar site, I'll take a look.

Comment: I have the problem somehow that my string is not reseted when, deleting the search term in the searchbar. So if I have no results for something and I want to make a new search I have to reload the app in order to see my list of users again.

Comment: the search function works but I can't reset the string when cleaning the input of the searchbar

Comment: @ColinRagnarök - Does it give different results when you change the string? If you can share the code, I'll take a look, it would be a simple fix. I can't say anything without more info.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic  its not working though, since Im using a service which takes data from an api and you can only make ionic 3 code. But its basically the code there.

Comment: When I console.log the searchTerm it actually also changes. So probably it has something to do that the data is only fetched in the `ngOnInit`?

Comment: @ColinRagnarök - That's right, when you search you are only filtering the results you already fetched in `ngOnInit`. To get new results, you have to make another API call. But you should be able to search existing results. Also, I don't see your code in the linked StackBlitz.